# TCL Script receiving DDE

Tags: tcl, dde

I want to create a TCL application that receives data over DDE and displays it on a TK Widget. At the moment I' developing the app on a Wish Console.
I have an application that will send DDE data to Excel and I 'think' it is sending data to my TCL console (the app doesn't give out an error message) but I can't see the result :-(
In TCL stuff I have written in the past I have 'pushed' and 'pulled' data ofer DDE, my app has never been the recipient of a 'push'.
What should I be looking for in my console?

TIA
mark

Answer (score 1):

The call you are looking for is [`dde servername`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dde.htm#M6). You use it's `-handler` option to install a handler for the service name `TclEval` and the topic with the name you choose. The handler takes a single argument.

```
package require dde
dde servername -handler MyDdeHandler "MySampleTopic"
proc MyDdeHandler {request} {
    puts "The request was '$request'"
    return "this is an example response"
}
```

Note that the other side still has to talk to the correct service/topic.

---

Useful links:

- [TIP #120](http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/120)
- [Tcler's Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/9331)

Comment: Thankyou - this now works between two TCL consoles but I cannot get it to work with my primary application (simulink). I can get the simulink model to send data to Excel but not to TclEval :-(